# find groups by recursively adding connected elements

Tags: r, recursion, group-by

Consider I have a 5 x n matrix, where columns represent n different objects. Now for every object I could have maximum 5 connections to other objects. The entry in the matrix shows to which object I have a linkage. Now I want to find groups between these objects. A group should be defined as all objects that are directly or indirectly linked to each other. So when for object "1" I have a linkage to object "2" and for object 2 linkages to objects "3" and "4" and objects "3" and "4" have no further linkages, objects "1", "2", "3" and "4" build a group.

In the end I want a vector, the same length as the number of objects indicating to which group the object belongs to.

So when I add objects "5" and "6" to the example above that are linked to each other, but not to 1,2,3,4 I would get a vector like: groups=c(1,1,1,1,2,2)

Consider I have a matrix that is very large, I want to find a way of how to most effectively find these groups now.

I have added an example matrix using `dput()`

```
Data<-structure(c(NA, NA, "2", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
"4", NA, NA, NA, NA, "5", "7", NA, NA, NA, "8", "9", "7", NA, 
NA, "8", "9", "7", NA, NA, "9", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "9", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "13", NA, "12", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "15", "16", NA, NA, NA, "17", NA, 
"15", NA, NA, NA, "18", "16", NA, NA, "18", NA, NA, NA, NA, "19", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "20", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "24", NA, "23", NA, NA, NA, 
"25", NA, NA, NA, NA, "26", NA, NA, NA, "27", NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, "29", "27", NA, NA, "29", NA, NA, NA, NA, "31", "32", NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "33", "34", "31", NA, NA, "34", "36", 
"32", NA, NA, "36", "37", NA, NA, NA, "38", "39", "34", NA, NA, 
"39", "40", "36", NA, NA, "39", "40", "36", NA, NA, "40", NA, 
"37", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "39", NA, NA, NA, NA, 
"40", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "42", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, "45", NA, NA, NA, NA, "45", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "48", NA, NA, NA, NA, "49", NA, 
NA, NA, NA, "52", NA, NA, NA, NA, "53", "54", NA, NA, NA, "56", 
NA, "52", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "54", NA, NA, NA, 
NA, "55", NA, NA, NA, NA, "56", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "59", 
NA, "58", NA, NA, NA, "61", NA, NA, NA, "63", NA, NA, NA, NA, 
"63", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, "74", "71", NA, NA, "74", NA, "72", NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, "76", NA, NA, NA, NA, "77", NA, NA, NA, NA, "77", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "87", NA, 
"83", NA, NA, "87", NA, "83", NA, NA, NA, NA, "85", NA, NA, NA, 
NA, "85", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "89", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, "89", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, "95", NA, "92", NA, NA, NA, NA, "93", NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "95", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
"97", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), .Dim = c(5L, 
98L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", 
"7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", 
"18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", 
"29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", 
"40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50", 
"51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59", "60", "61", 
"62", "63", "64", "65", "66", "67", "68", "69", "70", "71", "72", 
"73", "74", "75", "76", "77", "78", "79", "80", "81", "82", "83", 
"84", "85", "86", "87", "88", "89", "90", "91", "92", "93", "94", 
"95", "96", "97", "98")))
```

Any help is very welcome!
Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the objects as nodes in a graph and the connections as the edges of the graph, what you are asking for is the connected components of the graph. The package `igraph` has many tools for working with graphs, including finding their connected components.  So one approach is to convert your `Data` matrix into the edgelist for a graph, make the graph and find the components. I find the format of your `Data` matrix a bit awkward to work with, so the conversion to an edgelist is just brute force, not very elegant. After that conversion, the rest is easy.

```
## Convert your matrix to an edgelist
EL = matrix(data=NA, nrow=0, ncol=2)
for(i in 1:ncol(Data)) {
    for(j in 1:5) {
        if(!is.na(Data[j,i])) { EL = rbind(EL, c(i,as.numeric(Data[j,i]))) }
    }
}
```

Let's take a look at what is now in edgelist.

```
head(EL, 10)
      [,1] [,2]
 [1,]    1    2
 [2,]    3    4
 [3,]    4    5
 [4,]    4    7
 [5,]    5    8
 [6,]    5    9
 [7,]    5    7
 [8,]    6    8
 [9,]    6    9
[10,]    6    7
```

If you compare with your matrix,  you can see how this captures the same information. It says that object 1 is connected to object 2. Object 3 is connected to object 4. etc.

Let's turn that into a graph.

```
library(igraph)
G = graph_from_edgelist(EL, directed=FALSE)
plot(G, vertex.size=10, margin=-0.2)
```

[image: Graph]

Now, the groups that you want are just the connected components. There is a function for that in `igraph`. It returns more information than just the groups so I will select only the group part.

```
components(G)$membership
 [1]  1  1  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  3  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  5  6  6  6  6
[26]  6  6  7  6  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  8  8  9  9  9 10 11 11 11 11
[51] 11 11 11 11 11 11 12 12 12 12 12 13 12 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 20 20 21 20 20
[76] 21 20 22 23 24 25 25 25 25 25 26 25 25 25 27 28 28 28 28 28 29 29
```

You can see that objects (nodes) 1 & 2 are in group 1. Objects 3,4,5,6,7,8 and 9 are in group 2. Object 10 is not connected to anything else so it is in a group by itself - group 3.

Comment: This is great! Thanks a lot.